# Trying to send email with SendGrid to an gmail email but I get a "Pending" message

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, vercel

I used this [guide](https://zeit.co/guides/deploying-nextjs-nodejs-and-sendgrid-with-zeit-now) as a reference to create the api with this service. The user just types a name, email, telephone and description and it's send to an email of gmail.

I'm using Zeit Now to create the api, this is the code written in TypeScript:

```
import sendGrid from "@sendgrid/mail";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import { IEmailValues } from "../../types/IEmailValues";

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { name, email, telephone, description }: IEmailValues = req.body;

  sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const content = {
    to: "rmcarga.logistica@gmail.com", // carga logistica email
    from: email,
    subject: `${name} requiere de un servicio.`,
    html: `
Nombre: ${name}<br>
Email: ${email}<br>
Teléfono: ${telephone}<br>
<p>${description}</p>
    `
  };

  try {
    sendGrid.send(content);
    res.status(200).send({ response: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).send({ response: false });
  }
};
```

[here's](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/carga-logistica) the complete code.

In development, it works great, here's the response:

[image]

But in production doesn't:

[image]

This is the site I'm using in production: https://carga-logistica.now.sh/

How can I resolve it? Thank you.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Have you got it resolved?

Comment: Yeah... same here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm trying to solve this without any luck